# Objective c Split String Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, split

I'm trying to split a string into an NSArray, however I'm having an issue ignoring strings that have speech marks in.

For example

```
NSString *example = @"100 200 300 \"TEST ITEM\" 500";
NSArray *array = [example componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

However the array obviously  gets created as 100, 100, 300, "Test, ITEM", 500. Is it possible to treat anything with " " as one?

Thanks

Comment: Split on `"` first, then split the even elements (0, 2, ...) on spaces.

Comment: @Kevin But what about cases with 3 words inside quotes?

Comment: @rmaddy that's why I said even elements. `@"a b \"c d e\" f g"` -> `@[@"a b ", @"c d e", @" f g"]`, split even -> `@[@"a", @"b", @"c d e", @"f", @"g"]` (taking care to remove empty elements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [a well known CSV Parser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) which can be configured to use spaces as separators, and will treat double-quotes correctly. That assumes you want usual CSV-handling like escaping of double-quotes inside double-quoted strings, etc.

Otherwise, you'll probably need to write the parsing logic yourself; take a look at `NSScanner`, which would let you read up to a space or double-quote, look at what you get back, and then read to the next space/double-quote, etc.

Example:

```
@interface ItemParser : NSObject<CHCSVParserDelegate>

- (NSArray *)itemsFromString:(NSString *)input;

@end

@implementation ItemParser {
    NSMutableArray *_results;
}

- (NSArray *)itemsFromString:(NSString *)input {
    _results = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSStringEncoding encoding = [input fastestEncoding];
        NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:[input dataUsingEncoding:encoding]];
    CHCSVParser *parser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithInputStream:stream usedEncoding:&encoding delimiter:' '];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];

    return _results;
}

- (void)parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didReadField:(NSString *)field atIndex:(NSInteger)fieldIndex {
    [_results addObject:field];
}
@end
```

You'd use it like this:

```
NSString *example = @"100 200 300 \"TEST ITEM\" 500";
ItemParser *parser = [[ItemParser alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [parser itemsFromString:example]);
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me all.

I've had a look into CHCSVParser and from the write up it looks like it will do what I want.

However I've added it to my project and I'm having issues getting to to parse. For example: NSString *example = @"100 200 300 \"TEST ITEM\" 500"; NSArray *test = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:example options:(CHCSVParserOptionsRecognizesComments)]; I just get empty elements?

Comment: @Strikeforce The method you're calling takes a file path; I don't know why it doesn't provide a better error then what you're seeing. If you want to configure CHCSVParser to use spaces for delimiters, you'll need to create an instance of the parser directly. I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `NSString` category that uses an `NSScanner` to split a string into search terms, respecting various types of quote pairs: `""` `''` `‘’` `“”`

Usage:

```
NSArray *terms = [@"This is my \"search phrase\" I want to split" searchTerms];
// results in: ["This", "is", "my", "search phrase", "I", "want", "to", "split"]
```

Code:

```
@interface NSString (Search)
- (NSArray *)searchTerms;
@end

@implementation NSString (Search)

- (NSArray *)searchTerms {

    // Strip whitespace and setup scanner
    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    NSString *searchString = [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:searchString];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil]; // we'll handle whitespace ourselves

    // A few types of quote pairs to check
    NSDictionary *quotePairs = @{@"\"": @"\"",
                                 @"'": @"'",
                                 @"\u2018": @"\u2019",
                                 @"\u201C": @"\u201D"};

    // Scan
    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *substring = nil;
    while (scanner.scanLocation < searchString.length) {
        // Check for quote at beginning of string
        unichar unicharacter = [self characterAtIndex:scanner.scanLocation];
        NSString *startQuote = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", unicharacter];
        NSString *endQuote = [quotePairs objectForKey:startQuote];
        if (endQuote != nil) { // if it's a valid start quote we'll have an end quote
            // Scan quoted phrase into substring (skipping start & end quotes)
            [scanner scanString:startQuote intoString:nil];
            [scanner scanUpToString:endQuote intoString:&substring];
            [scanner scanString:endQuote intoString:nil];
        } else {
            // Single word that is non-quoted
            [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:whitespace intoString:&substring];
        }
        // Process and add the substring to results
        if (substring) {
            substring = [substring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
            if (substring.length) [results addObject:substring];
        }
        // Skip to next word
        [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:whitespace intoString:nil];
    }

    // Return non-mutable array
    return results.copy;

}

@end
```